# React Code Working Perfectly on Localhost but returning Type Error when Hosted on Netlify

Tags: reactjs, deployment, compiler-errors, netlify

I have a small react project that I'm working on. I'm getting some news using an API. everything works well on localhost but not working on Netlify. It's returning a type error code on Netlify and the screen goes blank

link to the repo here

[Githubrepo](https://github.com/femakin/Global-Info)

Screenshot of the console error below. This is happening after deploying to netlify

[image]

Comment: hi, friend, do you wanna deploy the project on Netlify?

Comment: I saw your project. I can do this. but I think you post this project on freelacner.com. How about your think?

Comment: @Glisten have deployed but it's returning an error on the console when you attempt to search for a news but doesn't do that on localhost

Comment: Can you show me the error with screenshot?

Comment: Have added the screenshot @Glisten

Comment: That error is because, somewhere data is empty .... That get request is unsuccessful and hence some data is Missing

Comment: But It's working as expected on Localhost @NihalChandwani

Comment: Lot of error appear after deployment , for example cors error ,that basically a permission error .. but here in your case that may be different

Comment: I don't know what to do again. Have been on this for a while now

Comment: According to 426 status code ,The HTTP 426 Upgrade Required client error response code indicates that the server refuses to perform the request using the current protocol but might be willing to do so after the client upgrades to a different protocol. The server sends an Upgrade header with this response to indicate the required protocol(s).... .................So there may be chances that the API you are using charges for deployed project

Comment: oh! Thank you @NihalChandwani I will try and find out